# oozie coordinator trigger when any file in hdfs path

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

Im trying to create a oozie coordinator that execute workflow when add any file in a HDFS path, but i only found examples trigger the workflow with a specified file, Can i use something like regex in the done-flag?(dont work the sample added), Any suggestion??:

```
<coordinator-app name="coordinator_test" frequency="${frequency}" start="${start}" end="${end}" timezone="${timezone}" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
    <controls>
        <concurrency>1</concurrency>
        <execution>FIFO</execution>
        <throttle>5</throttle>
    </controls>
    <datasets>
        <dataset name="input1" frequency="2" initial-instance="2015-09-23T00:00Z" timezone="UTC">
            <uri-template>${nameNode}/user/oozie/test/created</uri-template>
            <done-flag>*</done-flag>
        </dataset>
    </datasets>
    <input-events>
        <data-in name="coordInput1" dataset="input1">
            <start-instance>${coord:current(-1)}</start-instance>
            <end-instance>${coord:current(0)}</end-instance>
        </data-in>
    </input-events>
    <action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>${nameNode}/user/oozie/workflow.xml</app-path>
        </workflow>
    </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

For different type of files I would specify different datasets with different uri-template, and specify the various file names/types there. They can point to the same location, and the filename (with wildchars) would specify the different type of sources.

Something like:

${hdfs}/students*

${hdfs}/teachers*

And use decision control node to process the data with the right script.

---

Try with

```
<done-flag></done-flag>
```

than it's triggers when the path is exists.

> done-flag: The done file for the data set. If done-flag is not
>   specified, then Oozie configures Hadoop to create a _SUCCESS file in
>   the output directory. If the done flag is set to empty, then
>   Coordinator looks for the existence of the directory itself.

Comment: sorry, i think that you dont understands my question, i want to use something like regular expresion to check if you put in HDFS any file, for example: if you put any file with .dat extension:      <done-flag>*.dat</done-flag> doesnt work

Comment: Oh, I got it. Can you explain the workflow you'd like to implement in Oozie?

Comment: i want ingest a file, aplying diferent rules to validate the type of the file, if i put a file call "students.dat" i aply the format of the table students and validate the file. The file in the path is the trigger to start the process.

Comment: Is it possible to use regex like that (${hdfs}/students*) in oozie-coordinator?